# How to import scoped style in component <NextJS>

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I import file css like `import './Login.module.css';`

in component `components/login/index.js`, I create element with class like

`<div className="authentication-wrapper authentication-basic container-p-y">`

But classes don't work

As far as I know, the css files are imported as

`import styles from '../styles/Login.module.css'`

and used as

`<div className={styles.container}>`

but i want to write class name straight into className

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could understand, your idea is to use scoped module CSS with custom class naming in the HTML.

This won't work because Next applies some custom naming to the module styling (which can be seen in the console)

I'd advise 2 solutions to this issue:

1. Fully benefit the module system on scoped CSS files in the same folder (component scoped style);
2. Use generic CSS files with specific class names (generic style).

I'll be using .tsx to refer to TypeScript React Components

**Example 1:**
Imagine having the folder Components, as shown

```
  Components
    ├── Base.tsx
    └── Base.module.css
```

Your CSS module-file will be like so:

```css
.authentication_wrapper {
  /* your style goes here */
}
```

The component will be like this:

```
import base from './Base.module.css'

export default function Base() {
  return <div className={base.authentication_wrapper}>
    {/* other stuff here */}
  </div>
}
```

**Example 2:**

Imagine having the folder Components, as shown

```
Components
  └── Base.tsx
```

And imagine having the styles folder, like this

```
styles
  └── base.css
```

your app.css file will be like this

```css
.authentication-wrapper {
  /* your style goes here */
}
```

Inside `/pages/_app.tsx`, you'll import the CSS as shown

```
import '../styles/base.css'
```

The component will be like this:

```
export default function Base() {
  return <div className='authentication-wrapper'>
    {/* other stuff here */}
  </div>
}
```

You can further document yourself with the [CSS Module Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css) of Next.js